# Where, in the WebKit Inspector js, does control return to the page being inspected?

Tags: webkit, chromium, web-inspector

I've been looking through the WebKit Inspector js that is available from the Chromium project here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/contributing

The developer tool can be put in 'inspect' mode using the magnifying glass button in the status bar.
The mode lasts for one click on the page being inspected. After one click, the page is no longer in 'inspect' mode.

I'd like to keep the inspected page in 'inspect' mode.

In the js, I've figured out where the inspector

enters 'inspect mode' after clicking on the magnifying glass button in the status bar)

- highlights the element in the page being inspected

  finds the associated node in the DOM

  displays the node and the rest of the tree in the Elements panel

  puts focus on the selected node in the DOM tree displayed in the Elements panel

I cannot figure out how the inspected page returns to 'normal' mode after being in 'inspect' mode.

I tried the following:

- once toggleSearchingForNode is enabled, preventing it from being disabled.

  in revealAndSelectNode, preventing the selected node from getting focus

Neither helped. After one click in the inspected page, the page returned to normal behavior.

Any help is appreciated.